# How to make a symbol remove itself at a certain frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm struggling on doing a simple thing, I have an object that generates a smoke trail by creating and adding a simple animation done in flash. All works fine but I can't seem to find an easy way to make the smoke remove itself after playing the animation, if i add something like `this.parent.removeChild(this);` to the last frame of the animation the app simply crashes with `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you adding the smoke animation via actionscript or have you added it to the timeline?

Comment: with actionscript i add the movieclip itself, when called, the movieclip simply plays by itself, in flash i added `this.parent.removeChild(this);` to the last frame of the movieclip

Comment: have you tried to trace the `parent`?

Comment: just did, and returns the correct object, which is the object parent to the movieclip

Comment: Maybe you could try to `stop()` it too? That way it won't crash the second time it reaches the end of the animation and `parent` is `null` after having been removed the first time. Or do you get the error immediately when removing it?

Comment: ok that did it, adding `stop();` solved it, i didn't know the animation kept playing in the background, i thought the animation was somewhat tied to the rendering engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the animation keeps playing even thought the object is no longer being rendered, at the second call of `this.parent.removeChild(this);` the object was no longer parented to any object, stopping the animation solved the problem

thank you frankhermes

```
this.parent.removeChild(this);
this.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

in your main Movie clip assigned below code to a button(show button):

---

```
var swfLoader:Loader = new Loader();
stage.addChild(swfLoader);

var swfURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("yourchildSWF.swf");

swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
swfLoader.load(swfURL);

    function loadComplete(e:Event):void 
        {
            //swfLoader.x = (stage.stageWidth-swfLoader.width)/2; //for center align
            //swfLoader.y = (stage.stageHeight-swfLoader.height)/2; //for center align

            swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete); 
            swfLoader.content.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:Event) 
                {
                    swfLoader.unload();                                 
                } ); 

        }
```

---

you must have a button in your child swf. when pressed on it, swf will be closed.(create a symbole as button for close button)

- does not need any code in child swf.